# Overflow-x and overflow-y properties, how should they work?

Tags: css, cross-browser, frontend

The CSS properties overflow-x and overflow-y should be well supported by all major browsers. [So says w3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp). I've just made an example where we can see that they behave poorly when the `visible` value comes into play.

You can find the example code [here on github](https://gist.github.com/miphe/6421189) or [a working live example](http://overflow.miphe.com).

So the irregular behaviour that I see when it comes to the `visible` value is what I'm trying to avoid. I would like a vertical scroll (`auto` or `scroll`), and `visible` overflowing content horizontally. Have just tried this on Chrome and FireFox

How can I solve this, and is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at this the wrong way. If you want content to continue outside your div, maybe you should be using absolute positioning or a different layout structure?

Comment: @Coop My requirements is a container that will create a scroll-y when needed, and let me position boxes within it (absolute). These boxes will be on the x-edge of the container, they should not be clipped. I'll try a different layout structure but I'm not sure how to get around this still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, see the [w3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x).

What it boils down to is that in instances where it is not possible to have visible and hidden together, the visible is set to auto instead.

Comment: All right, I see I have to solve this in another way. But how can this be desired/expected behaviour, the x/y of overflow is meant to be used in combination and this means that there's really a slim way of using them. I don't see how auto -x would mean that visible -y would be impossible, I don't see the conflict.

Comment: @miphe This is how the spec has defined it, I do not know the motivation behind this behaviour.  It does make it messy trying to work around it.